# Laravel Chart doesn't render the graph. Undefined variable: chart

Tags: laravel, charts

I'm new in Laravel Chart. I followed all the steps in the guide (https://charts.erik.cat/getting_started.html). I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and I loaded the C3 library:
'''php artisan make:chart alarmChart C3'''
My controller:
'''public function testChart()
    {

```
    $chart = new SampleChart;
    $chart->labels(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']);
    $chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
    $chart->dataset('My dataset 2', 'line', [4, 3, 2, 1]);

    return view('AlarmMonitoring.Dashboard.alarmDashboard', compact('chart'));
}'''
```

My Route:
'''Route::get('/AlarmMonitoring/AllAlarms/Dashboard', 'AlarmChartController@testChart');'''
and my view:
'''@extends('templates.2_layout')

@section('content')
@include('templates.alarmMonitoringMenu')

## TESTING CHARTS

{!! $chart->container() !!}

@endsection

@section('javascripts')
    @parent

```
{!! $chart->script() !!}
```

@endsection'''

I don't understand why the error is returned: Undefined variable: chart.
can anyone help me understand?
Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the original

```
use App\Charts\sampleChart;
```

in my personal

```
use App\Charts\alarmChart;
```